# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

```js
public List<Floor> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
        {
            var result = (from floor in db.Floors
                       join camp in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals camp.ID
                       join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                       where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                       select new
                       {
                           Floor = floor.ID,
                           Campus = camp.ID,
                           Building = build.ID,
                              floor.ID,
                              floor.Floor_Name,
                              camp.Campus_Name,
                              build.Building_Name

                          }).ToList();

            return result;

        }
```

Comment: Maybe `Select new Floor { ` instead of anonymous type `Select new {`?

Comment: I try this one  but show an error in return type

Comment: That mean structure of anonymous type is different than structure of type `Floor`. You need to decide what type you want to be a return type. If return type should be something else than `Floor` then create new type and use it as return type for the function. `public List<FloorWithBuildingInformation> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public object GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
        {
            var result = (from floor in db.Floors
                       join camp in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals camp.ID
                       join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                       where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                       select new
                       {
                           Floor = floor.ID,
                           Campus = camp.ID,
                           Building = build.ID,
                              floor.ID,
                              floor.Floor_Name,
                              camp.Campus_Name,
                              build.Building_Name

                          }).ToList();

            return result;

        }
```

or u should to create a new class
like this

```
class BuildingInfo
{
public int FloorId {Set ;get;}
public CampusId  {Set; get;}
public BuildingId {Set ;get; }
public sting FloorName {Set; get;}
public sting Campus_Name {Set; get;}
public sting Building_Name {Set ;get;}

}
```

and return the new type and i see that is better 
like this

```
select new BuildingInfo()
                       {
                           Floor = floor.ID,
                           Campus = camp.ID,
                           Building = build.ID,
                              floor.ID,
                              floor.Floor_Name,
                              camp.Campus_Name,
                              build.Building_Name

                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: first one is easier to implement than the second

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your result set as a class...

```
public class BuildingInfo
{
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public int Campus { get; set; }
    public int Building { get; set; }
    public int FloorId { get; set; }
    public string FloorName { get; set; }
    public string CampusName { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
}
```

...and then modify your `GetBuildingInfoByBuildId()` method to return a list of that type...

```
public static List<BuildingInfo> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
{
    var result = (from floor in db.Floors
                    join camp in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals camp.ID
                    join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                    where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                    select new BuildingInfo
                    {
                        Floor = floor.ID,
                        Campus = camp.ID,
                        Building = build.ID,
                        FloorId = floor.ID,
                        FloorName = floor.Floor_Name,
                        CampusName = camp.Campus_Name,
                        BuildingName = build.Building_Name

                    }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```